# Laravel Custom Validation of Two Dates

Tags: laravel, validation, date

I'm creating a form in Laravel which has two fields: `departure-date` and `return-date`. I'm trying to create custom validation logic where the departure date entered *MUST* be on the same day or any other date after the user fills in the form. The `return-date` should also be after the `departure date`. Kindly assist?

**Form Layout**

```
<!-- Departure date-->
<div class="form-line registar2 love {{ $errors->has('departure_date') ? ' has-error' : '' }}">
    <input type="date" class="form-input" name="departure_date" value="{{ old('departure_date') }}" required>
    <label>Departure Date *</label>
    <div class="error-label">Field is required!</div>
    <div class="check-label"></div>
    @if ($errors->has('departure_date'))
        <span class="help-block">
            <strong>{{ $errors->first('departure_date') }}</strong>
        </span>
    @endif
</div>
<!--End departure-->

<!-- Return date-->
<div class="form-line registar2 move {{ $errors->has('return_date') ? ' has-error' : '' }}">
    <input type="date" class="form-input" name="return_date" value="{{ old('return_date') }}" required>
    <label>Return Date *</label>
    <div class="error-label">Field is required!</div>
    <div class="check-label"></div>
    @if ($errors->has('return_date'))
        <span class="help-block">
            <strong>{{ $errors->first('return_date') }}</strong>
         </span>
    @endif
</div>
<!-- End return date-->
```

**Validation in Controller**

```
public function validatePlanEntries(Request $request)
{
    $validation = $this->validate($request, [
            'departure_date' => 'required',
            'return_date' => 'required'
        ]
    );
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
    public function validatePlanEntries(Request $request)
    {
        $validation = $this->validate($request, [
            'departure_date' => 'required|date|after:now',
            'return_date' => 'required|date|after:departure_date',
        ]
        );
    }
```

FYI: the after:xxxxx rule either compares to another input field or respects the rules of the native DateTime PHP class. So you may enter `after:now +2 hours`.

To override the messages and write your own, create a `messages()` function like this:

```
public function messages()
{
    return [
        'departure_date.required' => 'Departure date is required',
        'departure_date.after' => 'Please choose a date in the future',
        'return_date.required'  => 'Return date is required',
        'return_date.after' => 'Your return date is before departure'
    ];
}
```

Just in case you are looking for a jquery solution to make datepicking more user friendly and less error bound, you may have a look at [Bootstrap Datepicker](https://bootstrap-datepicker.readthedocs.io/en/stable/), it's probably worth the effort. Good luck on your project!

Comment: Thanks alot for your help,, how can I add a custom error message to display to the user

Comment: Well,, thanks alot what if I add another array inside validation Object instead of another function,, is it applicable `public
    function validatePlanEntries(Request $request)
    {

        $validation = $this->validate($request, [
            'departure_date' => 'required|date|after:now',
            'return_date' => 'required|date|after:departure_date'
        ], 
            [
'departure_date.after' => 'Choose a day after today',
            'return_date.after' => 'Choose a day after  departure  date'
        ]
        );
`

Comment: I don't think so. But you can create separated validation rules with the artisan command `make:request` and call these files where needed. For more information have a look at https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/validation#form-request-validation

Comment: Okay,, Thanks alot